# Является ли закомментированный код в файлах шаблонов антипаттерном?

Tags: шаблонизаторы, комментарии

Всем известно, что закомментированный код, особенно при условии использования системы версионирования, является антипаттерном (код с душком).

Нужно ли переносить это правило на код языка шаблонов (`Smarty`, `Twig` и т.п.)?

Более того: являются ли комментирование блоков предпочтительнее их удалению?

Comment: Комменты пишутся прежде всего для себя. Если это как-то облегчает задачу, то почему бы и нет? Пишите, не стесняйтесь!

Comment: `Всем известно, что закомментированный код, особенно при условии использования системы версионирования` - мне вот не известно. Откуда это взялось? Вот у меня код на миллиард строк. Я что, должен вспоминать, что там выводится и для чего  роясь в  версионках? Бред же.

Comment: Ну я понял, что русские об этом не знают. Суровые американские инженеры вам отвечают: http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/190222/74973

Comment: Кроме того, на моей предыдущей работе консультант критиковал меня за закоммиченный комментированный код.

Comment: OK, а теперь внимание вопрос: какого вида комментарии нужно или даже **нужно** использовать при комментировании "кода" в шаблонах а-ля `Smarty`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Закоментированный код считаю антипаттерном. Это моё личное мнение. Код должен работать, ему не зачем быть в комментариях.

*Далее выражаю общепринятую точку зрения, без относительности языка (Smarty, Twig и т.п.)*

### Плохие комментарии

В коде нужны комментарии.

Сразу начну с того, каких комментариев быть почти не должно.

**Должен быть минимум комментариев, которые отвечают на вопрос «что происходит в коде?**

Что интересно, в коде начинающих разработчиков обычно комментариев либо нет, либо они как раз такого типа: «что делается в этих строках».

Серьёзно, хороший код и так понятен.

Об этом замечательно выразился Р.Мартин в книге [«Чистый код»](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/21916535/): «Если вам кажется, что нужно добавить комментарий для улучшения понимания, это значит, что ваш код недостаточно прост, и, может, стоит переписать его».

Если у вас образовалась длинная «простыня», то, возможно, стоит разбить её на отдельные функции, и тогда из их названий будет понятно, что делает тот или иной фрагмент.

Да, конечно, бывают сложные алгоритмы, хитрые решения для оптимизации, поэтому нельзя такие комментарии просто запретить. Но перед тем, как писать подобное – подумайте: «Нельзя ли сделать код понятным и без них?»

### Хорошие комментарии

А какие комментарии полезны и приветствуются?

- **Архитектурный комментарий – «как оно, вообще, устроено».**

  Какие компоненты есть, какие технологии использованы, поток взаимодействия. О чём и зачем этот скрипт. Взгляд с высоты птичьего полёта. Эти комментарии особенно нужны, если вы не один, а проект большой.
- **Справочный комментарий перед функцией – о том, что именно она делает, какие параметры принимает и что возвращает.**

Для таких комментариев существует синтаксис [JSDoc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSDoc).

```
/**
 * Возвращает x в степени n, только для натуральных n
 *
 * @param {number} x Число для возведения в степень.
 * @param {number} n Показатель степени, натуральное число.
 * @return {number} x в степени n.
 */
function pow(x, n) {
  ...
}
```

Такие комментарии позволяют сразу понять, что принимает и что делает функция, не вникая в код.

Кстати, они автоматически обрабатываются многими редакторами, например Aptana и редакторами от JetBrains, которые учитывают их при автодополнении, а также выводят их в автоподсказках при наборе кода.

Кроме того, есть инструменты, например JSDoc 3, которые умеют генерировать по таким комментариям документацию в формате HTML. Более подробную информацию об этом можно также найти на сайте http://usejsdoc.org/.

**…Но куда более важными могут быть комментарии, которые объясняют не что, а почему в коде происходит именно это!**

Как правило, из кода можно понять, что он делает. Бывает, конечно, всякое, но, в конце концов, вы этот код видите. Однако гораздо важнее может быть то, чего вы не видите!

Почему это сделано именно так? На это сам код ответа не даёт.

Например:

**Есть несколько способов решения задачи. Почему выбран именно этот?**

Например, пробовали решить задачу по-другому, но не получилось – напишите об этом. Почему вы выбрали именно этот способ решения? Особенно это важно в тех случаях, когда используется не первый приходящий в голову способ, а какой-то другой.

Без этого возможна, например, такая ситуация:

- Вы открываете код, который был написан какое-то время назад, и видите, что он «неоптимален».
- Думаете: «Какой я был дурак», и переписываете под «более очевидный и правильный» вариант.
- …Порыв, конечно, хороший, да только этот вариант вы уже обдумали раньше. И отказались, а почему – забыли. В процессе переписывания вспомнили, конечно (к счастью), но результат – потеря времени на повторное обдумывание.

Комментарии, которые объясняют выбор решения, очень важны. Они помогают понять происходящее и предпринять правильные шаги при развитии кода.

**Какие неочевидные возможности обеспечивает этот код? Где ещё они используются?**

В хорошем коде должно быть минимум неочевидного. Но там, где это есть – пожалуйста, комментируйте.

> Комментарии – это важно. Один из показателей хорошего разработчика – качество комментариев, которые позволяют эффективно поддерживать код, возвращаться к нему после любой паузы и легко вносить изменения.